# Source code browsing, comprehension and reading tools

Tags: c, call-graph

I am primarily a C and C++ programmer and i often need to quickly comprehend the structure of very large code bases (gcc, linux kernel). I wonder if there are any tools to help in this regard. I am particularly interested in call graphs, data structure references across the project, include dependency graphs, quick symbol location, etc. I known about ctags and cscope but i am looking for something with more visualization like a call graph that allows to quickly locate definition of a function, root the graph at a particular call, inverting it (i.e. locating all calls to a given function), etc.

Comment: RTCM - read the compiler manual.  Most compilers do some of what you want and I expect that the compiler(s) you use are no exception.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to build call graphs, you could roll your own with GCC's [`-finstrument-functions`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html).

Basically, when you compile a program with that option enabled, GCC calls the following functions whenever the target program enters or exits a function:

```
      void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
                                     void *call_site);
      void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
                                     void *call_site);
```

What you need to do is define these functions, and write in your logic to produce the call graph there.

[This extremely thorough tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-graphvis/) explains how you could produce a call graph using `-finstrument-functions` and [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/). All the tools involved are FOSS and gratis.

Of course:

1. The graphs GraphViz produces are stand-alone, and not part of an IDE.
2. I'm not really sure if producing a call-graph of Linux (the kernel) is possible *in this way*.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and use [SourceInsight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/). It is quite helpful with browsing code and understanding it. It provides most of the features requested by you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try cflow. It gives you a graf of the calls of functions inside. It is not very flexible though.